# Add logo from direct path into webpage

Tags: html

I want to add a logo into my webpage, but the logo file is not in the same folder that has webpage html file in it so I can't use relative path (e.g. 
 ) to load logo but using direct path. I don't know how to deal with it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is something like

www

www/html

www/images

then you should be able to use something like

```
<img src="./images/filename.jpg">
```

note the period at the beginning of the path.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In src="../images/logo.jpg" will go back to one step and search for logo.jpg in images folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you cant use  a relative path no matter where you logo is. If it's in the same folder then:

```
<img src="./logo.png">
```

Comment: The html file is generated dynamically by C++ so I don't know the html folder path

Answer (score 0):

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

1. Starting with `"/"` returns to the root directory and starts there
2. Starting with `"../"` moves one directory backwards and starts there
3. Starting with `"../../"` moves two directories backwards and starts
   there (and so on...)
4. To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
   moving forward

   `<img src="../site/img/logo.jpg" alt="">        <!--file html to ../site/file.html-->`

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"
stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg>
```

If you want further more Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_svg_circle